# What's the terminal command for auto pressing [Y]?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

for ex: if I do like

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I might get the y/n question before installing an update.
What's the parameter to auto accept it.

Comment: I don't know it and I would assume it would be -y, but have you tried apt-get -? and see what the program itself says?

Comment: `--yes`  is the way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

Apt-get specific:

```
$man apt-get
[...]
-y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts
       and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation,
       such as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. 
[...]
--force-yes
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to continue
       without prompting if it is doing something potentially harmful.
       It should not be used except in very special situations.
       Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system!
```

General: the `yes` command:

```
$man yes
yes - output a string repeatedly until killed [...]
DESCRIPTION
   Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.
```

Since `yes` can't know anything about `apt-get` internals, it is probably equivalent to `--force-yes` and thus **dangerous**. If you still want to do it, you pipe the output of `yes` into `apt-get`:

```
yes | apt-get update
```